How to set icon for application that use login with apple feature?
Go to https://account.apple.com/account/manage
Click Sign in with Apple
You will see the list of app/web you have logged in with Apple.
I'm developing this app "Masa App" like in the screenshot below.

However, the image next to the app name appears to be the Apple logo.
How to set the app to have my own logo?
I have set the app icon in the appstoreconnect.apple.com.
The website has the favicon set correctly.
I have looked around at the developer.apple.com, but I can't find a way to upload my icon.


If your app isn’t even for sale yet, I highly doubt your icon will ever be promoted to production.

Cross-site duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/58475605/1549818

I don’t think you get to manage this directly. To confirm, use developer mode in the web browser of your choice and inspect the icons. In my case, they all are coming from Apple’s content delivery network.
Then you will want to ensure you follow all of the App Store Promotional Asset Guidelines for developers, follow the guidelines for all sizes of your app icon and submit the app for sale.

https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/app-icons
https://help.apple.com/asc/appspromoart/

Do everything they recommend as if you’re hoping they promote your app with a story on the public/primary App Store for each platform you will ship an app.
After it’s been purchased a few hundred times, I would check again and open a support request with Apple Developer if their pipeline to update shipping app icons might have other requirements or need a poke.

To my eye, you need to remove the ®️ and the One Stop Building Solution text from the thumbnail icon. Apple design guidelines explicitly say to avoid what your employer asked you to do. Remember, you are talking about a thumbnail that needs to be legible and clear at a glance, not a hero website where you can include all the marketing and words you need.

https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/app-icons


Embrace Simplicity Avoid adding too many details, because they can be hard to discern and can make an icon appear muddy, especially at smaller sizes. Avoid adding too many details, because they can be hard to discern and can make an icon appear muddy, especially at smaller sizes.


Text in icons is often too small to read easily, can make an icon appear cluttered, and doesn’t support accessibility or localization. In some contexts, the app name appears near the icon, making it redundant to display the name within it.

Regardless if you ignore or follow Apple’s guidelines, I doubt your icon will show publicly until after it’s for sale.
I have 30 icons in my list, 5 apps get the generic treatment like yours and only 3 of the 30 have any text more than one large letter. Most have no text at all. Even some of the apps without icons have been for purchase for several years, so I don’t think smaller volume apps are guaranteed a custom icon based on my few close looks at this feature.

Thank you for the response.
The icon is for the Sign in with Apple, I think it should not matter if the mobile app is released or not, as user will sign in to the website anyway. The app is just a webview showing the website.
Are those 25 web/apps that have their icon, have an app released to the app store?
Also thank you for the suggestion, but both the ®️ and the One Stop Building Solution are required by my employer. I initially uploaded the icon without it, but they demanded the completed icon like this.

Yes, every one with an icon has been on the App Store for more than 2 years @ChristhoferNatalius good luck with the requirements you can’t change. I doubt Apple would ever share your icon until after every approval from them is complete. Even after, they may not deliver your custom icon publicly if not enough people choose to Sign in with Apple against your released app.
